# Media player with audio fade-out feature

Tags: windows, media-player

Im looking for a media player (or an audio player) in which during playback when the pause or stop button is pressed the audio must fade out instead of cutting out instantly.

This feature is present in Winamp and many Android audio players. Just want to know if there is a player for PC (Windows) that has the same feature.

Comment: Winamp is available for PC, does that not work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[foobar2000](https://www.foobar2000.org/) is an advanced freeware audio player for the Windows platform.

[image: foobar 2000 preferences for "Fading → Pause and stop": "Fade in" and "Fade out" can be set in ms]

Answer (score 0):

[Replayer](https://replayer.app/) does this. (I am the author). You can choose among a set of fade-in/fade-out times, separately.

Replayer is a browser-based solution, mostly intended for musical practice, so may or may not fit your general use case.

[image: Replayer fading settings]

At each play and pause, the fading times gets applied beforehand.